# Is there a "better" format to input data to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I started to use TF 2 month ago, but I’m still not sure about the input data format. Currently, I use raw binary format, because I think it's fast and portable. However, I know there are TFRecord, reading directly from PNG/JPG file and using feeding dictionaries from memory. Would anyone suggest a “better” format?

Comment: better than TFRecords?

Comment: Actually among them, but from your answer, TFR would be the best one to use when we have a choice.